# Tensorflow: complex custom loss. How to change tensors, based on complex conditions?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, tensor

I am trying to implement the OCCD (i.e. *Optimal color composition distance*) as loss function in tensorflow. Here is the research paper https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2555211_Optimal_Color_Composition_Matching_of_Images by Jianying Hu and Aleksandra Moj Silovic.
I somehow managed to make it work, but it is very slow and works only witch *batch_size = 1*. Follows a short explanation of what OCCD is about and a simple example written with numpy.

To make it simple, I have to change the pixels of an image which are *domined* by other color, meaning that the other color is very present in the pixel neighborhood. Follows a more detailed explanation.

I have a tensor of shape **[1024, 1024, 3]** representing an image in a reduced color space .
I have then a tensor *codebook* of shape **[100, 3]** representing all the RGB colors that the image above can contain.

I need to remove the noise added in the quantization phase (when the image, starting from the whole RGB space, get quantized to the codebook color space), in the following way:

1. First define D_size as a int value, typically 3-5;
2. For every color *c*<sub>*i*</sub> present in the codebook: for every pixel *p*<sub>*i*</sub> of that color, we examine its DxD neighborhood and count the total of every other color present in the neighborhood. Then divide by the total number of pixel in the neighborhood of **every** pixel of color *c*<sub>*i*</sub>.

To make it easier to understand, I need to come up with a so called *neighborhood color histogram*, which is a square matrix of size: ****[len(codebook), len(codebook)]****. We have every possible color as rows and columns.

Every row of the matrix represents a color, and every item in that row represents the presence of the color indicated by the column in the neighborhoods of all pixel of color indicated in row.

Simple example, where colors are identified by only 1 value (not rgb):

```
import numpy as np
import skimage

np.random.seed(11)

D_size = 3
image_size = 4
```

where *D_size* is the size of the square neighborhood

```
random_image = np.random.randint(low=1, high=5, size = [image_size, image_size])
random_image_pad = np.pad(random_image, 1, 'constant', constant_values= 0 )
codebook = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
```

*Codebook* represents 5 possible RGB color (this is a semplification to make the example more understandable) and the image is generated as random:

```
[ [2 4 1 4]  
  [2 4 2 1]  
  [2 4 3 1]  
  [2 1 1 2] ]
```

```
patches = skimage.util.view_as_windows(random_image_pad, D_size, step = 1)
patches = np.reshape(patches, (image_size * image_size, D_size, D_size))

CHM = np.zeros([len(codebook), len(codebook)], dtype = int)
```

patches contain all the *D_size x D_size* patches of the image

```
for patch in patches:
  for i in range (0, D_size):
    for j in range (0, D_size):
      if not (i==1 and j==1):
        x = patch[1][1]
        y = patch[i][j]
        CHM[x][y] = CHM[x][y] + 1

#Remove row and column 0 as 0 is not a valid color, it is used for padding 
CHM = np.delete(CHM, 0,0)
CHM = np.delete(CHM, 0, 1)
```

Here the *neighborhood color histogram* is built:

```
[ [8 7 4 6]  
  [7 6 2 12]  
  [4 2 0 2]  
  [6 12 2 4] ]
```

To make it more clear, the first **8** in the matrix means that, considering all pixel of color **1** in the image, the total **1** comparing in their neighborhood are **8**. The **7** in the first row indicates that the color **2** compares **7** times in the neighborhood of color **1**.

Now every row need to be divided by the sum of the row:

```
CHM = CHM / CHM.sum(axis=1)[:, None]

# CHM = [[0.25       0.08333333 0.625      0.04166667]
         [0.4        0.         0.4        0.2       ]
         [0.31914894 0.04255319 0.5106383  0.12765957]
         [0.125      0.125      0.75       0.        ]]
```

The next step is to identify the *domined colors*, that are the colors that satisfy the following conditions:

- In the neighborhood of all pixel of color *c*<sub>*i*</sub>, the most present color is NOT *c*<sub>*i*</sub>;
- The most present color in the neighborhood of all possible color *c*<sub>*i*</sub> is *c*<sub>*j*</sub>, which ratio *c*<sub>*j*</sub>/*c*<sub>*i*</sub> > threshold

```
threshold = 2
domined_color_matrix = np.zeros(len(codebook), dtype = int)

for i in range (0, len(CHM)):
  for j in range(0, len(CHM)):
    if i != j and CHM[i][j] == np.amax(CHM[i]) and CHM[i][j] / CHM[i][i] > threshold:
      domined_color_matrix[i] = j

# domined_color_matrix = [0 0 0 1 0]
```

The above matrix shows that color 3 is domined by color 1, so the last step is to replace every 3 with 1 in the original image:

```
for i in range (0, image_size):
  for j in range (0, image_size):
    if domined_color_matrix[random_image[i][j] ] > 0:
      random_image[i][j] = domined_color_matrix[random_image[i][j] ]

# original_image = [[2 4 1 4]
                    [2 4 2 1]
                    [2 4 3 1]
                    [2 1 1 2]]
# random_image = clan_image = [[2 4 1 4]
                               [2 4 2 1]
                               [2 4 1 1]
                               [2 1 1 2]]
```

I know this is not the best method to implement it, it is just to make it (hopefully) easier to understand. My problem is to implement it in tensorflow, to take advantage of paralleling processing. In particular I am not able to write a function that does the above computation on a batch of images.

This is one of my first question on Stack Overflow, so I hope it is clear enough. Thank in advance to everyone that will read it.

Comment: You have put a lot of effort into the explaining the question which is good, but it might be helpful if you can identify the problematic (slow part) and reduce the problem to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try to split the problem into simpler subproblems and ask multiple question.